# prolog database read input from terminal and retract it from the current database

Tags: database, io, prolog

In the code below, I would like to find a way to first read in a Character
   (by user typing '3.' and then remove/retract the number of that Character from
   the listCharacters database

```
 :- dynamic listCharacters/1.  

 listCharacters(Joe).  
 listCharacters(Tom).  
 listCharacters(Peter).  

 :- write_ln('Type in the name of the character you have from the below list.    
  Example "Tom" '), write_ln('1. Joe'), write_ln('2. Tom'), write_ln('3. Peter'),   
  read(X), retract(listOfCharacters(X)).
```

Answer (score 0):

first you should read elements in a list, then build your menu based on that content, something like

```
:- dynamic listCharacters/1.

listCharacters('Joe').
listCharacters('Tom').
listCharacters('Peter').

menu :-
    findall(Elem, listCharacters(Elem), L),

    format('Type in the index of the character you have from the below list.~n', []),
    forall(nth1(I,L,E), format('~d. ~q~n', [I, E])),

    read(X),
    (   nth1(X,L,E),
        retract(listCharacters(E))
    ->  true
    ;   format('cannot remove ~q', [X])
    ).
```

I've introduced a `menu` procedure, if you insist on calling it on consult add `:- menu.` at bottom of file. Some test:

```
?- menu.
Type in the index of the character you have from the below list.
1. 'Joe'
2. 'Tom'
3. 'Peter'
|: 2.
true.

?- menu.
Type in the index of the character you have from the below list.
1. 'Joe'
2. 'Peter'
|: 1.
true.
```